# Why do you need two Current methods for IEnumerator<T> in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I'm writing a class that implements the interface IEnumerator. To get it to compile, I need the following two methods:

```
public object Current
{
    get { return current; }
}

T IEnumerator<T>.Current
{
    get { return current; }
}
```

Why are both of these necessary? On the surface, it looks like only the latter is needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) implements the [`IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) interface which is the non-generic version of the interface that existed before generics were introduced in .NET 2.0. So when implementing an interface (`IEnumerator<T>` in your case) you need to also implement all other interfaces that this interface implements.

Comment: One reason that it implements the non-generic version is to allow backwards compatibility with other classes and methods that were not updated to take generics.  A large portion of the BCL wouldn't have been usable with generic types, had it not.